# WPF TabControl with ViewModel enabled TabItem content creation

Tags: wpf, data-binding, viewmodel, tabcontrol, tabitem

I want to create a TabControl where the TabItem would be created dynamically at runtime. The TabItem should be associated with a ViewModel. This view model supports an interface which knows how to create the content inside the TabItem. So basically TabItems could take in any content control decided by the view model at runtime. I have tried different approaches using TabControl.ContentTemplate or ControlTemplate and ItemTemplate, but none of them works. It seems that the templates approach needs to know the type of the content inside the TabItem at design time to be able to render itself. The bindings to a property in the associated data context works fine, but the Content Control is not displayed. 
Could we just derive a new class MyTabItem:TabItem and create the a custom content and associate it with the content of MyTabItem. 
Any generic approach which could allow the view model to create the content of TabItems is needed.

Comment: ok.. I could derive my CustomTabItem:TabItem and create its content in the constructor by passing in the view model. The ViewModel creates the content element and assigns it to the content of tabitem. what are the pros and cons of such an approach. I dont see any answers with this approach on stackoverflow. Allowing the viewModel to create the tabItems content seems like a very standard problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to specify a `DataTemplate` for each type which might be dynamically added to your `TabControl`? If so, would something like this work for you?

(Note that the `TabControl` is finding the same `DataTemplate` for both the `ItemTemplate` (the template of the tab header) and the `ContentTemplate` (the template displayed inside the content of the selected tab). This is because we have specified neither, so WPF is simply walking up the tree and finding the same template for both from our `Grid.Resources`. If you wanted to use a different template for each you could explicitly specify the template to be used for `ItemTemplate` if that works for you, or use a `DataTemplateSelector` or similar.)

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DescribableOne}">
            <Grid Background="Red">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DescribableTwo}">
            <Grid Background="Blue">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DescribableThree}">
            <Grid Background="Green">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Command="{Binding AddOne}">Add One</Button>
        <Button Command="{Binding AddTwo}">Add Two</Button>
        <Button Command="{Binding AddThree}">Add Three</Button>
    </StackPanel>

    <TabControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding DynamicallyGeneratedTabs}"/>

</Grid>
```

And the view model:

```
public class TabControlViewModel
{
    public TabControlViewModel()
    {
        AddOne = new RelayCommand(DoAddOne);
        AddTwo = new RelayCommand(DoAddTwo);
        AddThree = new RelayCommand(DoAddThree);
        DynamicallyGeneratedTabs = new ObservableCollection<IDescribable>();
    }

    public ICommand AddOne { get; }
    public ICommand AddTwo { get; }
    public ICommand AddThree { get; }

    public ObservableCollection<IDescribable> DynamicallyGeneratedTabs { get; }

    private void DoAddOne()
    {
        DynamicallyGeneratedTabs.Add(new DescribableOne());
    }

    private void DoAddTwo()
    {
        DynamicallyGeneratedTabs.Add(new DescribableTwo());
    }

    private void DoAddThree()
    {
        DynamicallyGeneratedTabs.Add(new DescribableThree());
    }
}

public interface IDescribable
{
    string Description { get; }
}

public class DescribableOne : IDescribable
{
    public DescribableOne()
    {
        Description = "One";
    }

    public string Description { get; }
}

public class DescribableTwo : IDescribable
{
    public DescribableTwo()
    {
        Description = "Two";
    }

    public string Description { get; }
}

public class DescribableThree : IDescribable
{
    public DescribableThree()
    {
        Description = "Three";
    }

    public string Description { get; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @simon for the answer. In the example you have posted, we know the type of content in the data template at design time( the TextBlock) . Where as I do not the Type. Ok to be more specific, my tab items needs to display graphs and some other subcontrols like a table. However I do not know how many graphs will be displayed at design time, it depends on the ViewModel. I want to specify a ContentControl instead of a TextBlock, but I guess that does not work. e.g like this
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding Description}"/>